How to debug connection drops between macOS host and Linux guest?
Note that I am cross-posting this from superuser as I was unable to resolve this issue and haven gotten any replies yet. Maybe this community is more suited to help? Thank you!

I run a Fedora Server VM on macOS Sonoma via UTM. UTM is configured to use a shared network, which creates a VLAN the VM joins and through which the host OS can discover it.
This all works fine, but in what appears to be random intervals, all network connections from macOS to the VM suddenly drop and remain broken. The only "fix" I have found is to reboot the VM, which returns everything to a working state. Since I SSH into the VM to perform work, this usually surfaces as request timeouts with SSH becoming unresponsive. Even pings to the VM will fail.
I suspected a routing issue (perhaps with the route dropping out of macOS's routing table?) but cannot find any evidence. The problem is that I don't know enough about networking internals, especially not with virtualization tech in between. This means I am currently "streetlighting" this problem because I don't even know where to look.
Could someone point me in the right direction here? Some facts below.
On the host
The VM hostname is work, IPv4 address is 192.168.64.2. I don't think it's a problem with IP lease because even after connections fail, it remains to have the same IP.
Pings and traceroutes to the VM will now fail:
$ traceroute 192.168.64.2

traceroute to 192.168.64.2 (192.168.64.2), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  *^C

$ ping 192.168.64.2

PING 192.168.64.2 (192.168.64.2): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3

The routing table looks OK though, AFAICT:
$ netstat -rn -f inet


Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags               Netif Expire
default            192.168.178.1      UGScg                 en0
default            link#24            UCSIg           bridge100      !
127                127.0.0.1          UCS                   lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH                    lo0
169.254            link#15            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.64         link#24            UC              bridge100      !
192.168.64.1       62.3e.5f.73.14.64  UHLWI                 lo0
192.168.64.2       8a.c3.94.a.86.e2   UHLWIi          bridge100   1199
192.168.178        link#15            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.178.1/32   link#15            UCS                   en0      !
192.168.178.1      dc:15:c8:ef:b8:1d  UHLWIir               en0   1198
192.168.178.52/32  link#15            UCS                   en0      !
224.0.0/4          link#15            UmCS                  en0      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI                en0
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWIg         bridge100
255.255.255.255/32 link#15            UCS                   en0      !

And when I drill into this specific route:
$ route get 192.168.64.2


   route to: work
destination: work
  interface: bridge100
      flags: <UP,HOST,DONE,LLINFO,WASCLONED,IFSCOPE,IFREF>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500      1200

Bridge network interface (this is created by UTM as part of the VLAN I believe?)
ifconfig bridge100


bridge100: flags=8a63<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,ALLMULTI,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether 62:3e:5f:73:14:64
    inet 192.168.64.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.64.255
    inet6 fe80::603e:5fff:fe73:1464%bridge100 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x18
    inet6 fd5d:9cb:9b9e:3946:141b:1dc6:2328:9f96 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: vmenet0 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 23 priority 0 path cost 0
    Address cache:
        8a:c3:94:a:86:e2 Vlan1 vmenet0 1199 flags=0<>
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active

ARP lookups seem to work:
$ arp work


work (192.168.64.2) at 8a:c3:94:a:86:e2 on bridge100 ifscope [bridge]

On the guest
I couldn't see anything out of the ordinary here either.

So bridge100 on the host is enp0s1 on the guest and it is UP.
I started looking for NetworkManager entries in journalctl as well, but since I don't really know what I was looking for I wasn't sure what to focus on.
I'd appreciate any help.

UPDATE 1:
As suggested in the comments, I ran a TCP capture in Wireshark. Around the time of the connection loss, I see 3 RST packets on 3 different TCP streams:

But since even pings are broken thereafter, this is probably a symptom, not a cause?
UPDATE 2:
I captured all traffic on bridge100 now and after the disconnect, I see a pattern in ARP requests. Before the disruption, 192.168.64.1 (the macOS host) keeps asking who is 192.168.64.2 (the VM) and receives a reply each time:

However, after the disruption, I see the host starting to broadcast the same question instead of addressing it to the VM's network interface directly (8a:c3:94:a:86:e2 is the VM's network IF); also, now the VM in return is starting to ask who has 192.168.64.1 which is the host (it did not do that before):

This seems to imply to me:

The host is not getting an answer anymore for ARP lookups; however, when I run arp work it still seems to have cached the original MAC, as mentioned in above. So not sure if this is just another symptom, not a cause?
The VM does not know anymore which MAC address is associated with 192.168.64.1; when I run arp 192.168.64.1, it comes back as (incomplete) for HWaddress. This would at least explain that it is now impossible for the VM to reply to any network packets received from the host.

UPDATE 3:
Around the same time it just happened, I was seeing Spurious retransmission errors in TCP streams:

On the VM itself, I looked for a similar timestamp in journalctl and noticed that systemd-resolved (Fedora's primary DNS resolver) started to fail over into alternative DNS resolution schemes:

Again, not sure if symptom or cause.


The first thing is to perform a packet capture to determine which end is sending a RST.

That's a great idea @GregAskew -- running Wireshark now on bridge100. Would you just capture all the traffic for now and filter later?

@GregAskew It just happened again while I was recording TCP exchanges, and no one sent a reset. So I suspect this means it is not an issue with TCP client/server hanging up on each other, but something else. I suspected routing at first, but as I mention in the question, routing table looks OK?

Come to think of it, if even pings fail this is unlikely to be a problem with the transport layer? Doesn't ping use ICMP (and ARP) to find the destination?

My bad -- there were 3 RST messages, I am not sure why they first didn't show when filtering. But the payload is encrypted (likely this is from SSH streams) so I am not sure what this is telling me. But as far as who hung up on whom, it was Host to VM. So it is the client-side (macOS) that is closing the stream. Isn't this just a symptom though, not a cause, since whenever this happens, I can not even  ping the VM anymore, which shouldn't rely on TCP?

I also found this related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/290601/ssh-disconnection-issue-tcp-rst-packets

I added more information from another, broader, network capture that shows that ARP lookups are now failing in both directions.
